# DNN: Whole site with HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: iis, ssl, https, dotnetnuke

I already found some good sources with hints and tips like http://blog.laksha.net/2008/03/enabling-ssl-in-dotnetnuke-and.html about running DNN with SSL.

My question is: If I would like to change the whole site (not only single pages) to SSL, do I need to configure anything in DNN? Or is it enough to install the certificate (and probably configure IIS)?

Thx

Comment: You should be able to configure everything VIA IIS.

Answer (score 1):

To affect just on portal you can set SSL enable for the portal and then update the Secure flag on every page. To do it rapidly run  following sql script, after do backup:

```
update tabs
set IsSecure = 1
where portalid =<portal id number>
```

Restart the site.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough just to install the certificate in IIS. Then you need to have IIS redirect to that protocol. Just google 'IIS redirect to https', that should tell you everything you need.

Comment: I'll give it a try this way and will post here about the result, thx.